# How to hide a API key on Javascript?

Tags: javascript, api, javascript-objects, hide

I am trying to hide an API key for a project using vanilla javascript. Any help in how to do that?

this is my javascript script.js

```
const API_KEY1 = 'abcdKey123'

async function getAllPosts() {
  // fetch the data from the api and put inside a promise
  const fetchAPI = await fetch(`https://gnews.io/api/v4/top-headlines?token=${API_KEY1}&lang=en`)

  // transform the data in json
  const apiJson = fetchAPI.json()
  // return the data
  return apiJson
}
```

How do I hide that key information and still use it?
Can you guys tell me a step by step? I've looked at some youtube videos and none really give a straight answer.

Thank you.

Comment: Is this front end JS or Node?

Comment: You can use external config file or as .env file if you are using some framework and share config file only to people you want to share keys.

Comment: This looks like front-end code. You never want to give a browser a key like that, there's no way to keep the user from extracting it. You have to build a server (i.e. in node) that holds the key and provides endpoints a client can use instead. (so the client uses your server endpoints instead of trying to use this API directly. Your server will use the API in behalf of the client)

Answer (score 0):

IF it is nodeJS, you can create a DOT_ENV file and put that into a gitignore file, I am assuming you are using github or gitlab for version control.

For the front end, it is impossible to hide them, as far I am aware. You can obfuscate them , but never hide in front end code.

Just use a bit PHP on the back end or run a NodeJS server on the back end.

Really, go right ahead and learn some PHP and NodeJS, I do all JS things in Node + Express if I can. These days, even front end devs are expected to understand a database and the backend. In general PHP is easier to learn (Even if you know JS) and more stable. But once you get the hang of NodeJS, it is quite enjoyable if the projects purpose is compatible.

But yes, whatever you do not want to expose to the users has to be saved on your server.

Comment: But what if it is just a weather app? something that  I just want to display the data that I fetch from an API? I don't need a back-end for that. Shouldn't have a way to hide that API_KEY in some sort?

Comment: @lenilunderman if you had to generate an API key to use the weather app, then you have to use a backend to hide the key. If a browser can get its hands on information to use it, then so can any user.

Comment: @lenilunderman there is no way to hide front end code, this is due to the nature of the browser. You say this is a weather API key, someone could use it for commercial use for millions of daily requests(which are not free at that scale). It is bad practice, you don't want any future employer to see this kind of thing. Even if it is a hobby project, do not do it. If it is a commercial project, this would be reckless behaviour towards the paying customer. If you have nodejs installed, setting up a server takes 2 minutes. PHP takes a bit more time.

Comment: To add a bit more, you never know, this might start as something small and then scale to the new google map for weather APIs in the future, better to be safe. You will be limiting yourself for many uses cases like email keys for sending data, confirmation SMS, payment methods etcetc. You do not need a full back end, not even a database, just a server and a DOT_ENV file within a gitignore. I am not sure if DOT_ENV is totally safe outside from a gitignore, never tried.

Comment: So, even if it is a simple application I need a node.js server?

Comment: So I am guessing I will need to use express for this simple app right? that's the only way I will be able to storage the key? I will need a back-end running. @scotty jamison

Comment: Yes, you can use express to do it.

Comment: There is even npx express generator , this will give you the app scaffold and a server in few seconds.